# UIView vs UITableCellView to show user posts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My app has a home screen where I show user posts loaded from the server. My problem is that I use UIView for each post, but it takes up a lot of space (also the user keeps on scrolling making it more memory consuming). Ex:

```
        UIView* box=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, postY, maxWidth, 500)];
        [box setTag:(NSInteger)[post_id[i] integerValue]];

        [box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        //Profile pic+++
        UIImageView* profile_img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
        profile_img.layer.cornerRadius=profile_img.frame.size.width/2; //Make it round
        profile_img.layer.masksToBounds=YES; //Make it round
        profile_img.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
        profile_img.layer.borderColor=[rgb(214, 222, 231) CGColor];

        [box addSubview:profile_img];
```

*And so on*...
Does anyone know a better way of doing this? I tough of UITableCellView but it seems to be odd doing this task this way

Comment: Why not using `UITableView` Or `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Is it possible to attach Labels and Buttons to them?

Comment: Ofcause it's possible.

Comment: Ya you should use custom UITableViewCell Or Collection View for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use a `UITableViewController` and then subclass `UITableViewCell` to create a custom cell for you to display the data. A `UITableViewController` instance contains a `UITableView` and you display the data by setting it in your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. So basically, a `UITableView` contains various `UITableViewCell` and use the delegate methods to respond to events and actions on your table.

```
// YourCustomTableViewCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

// Setup the properties for the cell, e.g
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImageView; // Connect to outlet in storyboard file

@end

// YourCustomTableViewCell.m
#import "YourCustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation YourCustomTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Use this method to setup frames and sizes of your properties
    self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width/2; //Make it round
    self.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES; //Make it round
    self.profileImageView.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
    self.profileImageView.layer.borderColor = [rgb(214, 222, 231) CGColor];
}

@end

// YourTableViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end

// YourTableViewController.m
#import "YourTableViewController.h"
#import "YourCustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface YourTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation YourTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Setup your data source for the table
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    // Setup other stuff after loading the view
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; // Return the number of sections you want in the table view
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows for each section, in your case this would be something like this
    return self.posts.count; // If your data is stored in an array
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"YourCustomCell";
    YourCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell){
        cell = [[YourCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    // Here you add the code to display the data in the cell e.g.
    [cell.profileImageView setImage:yourImageToDisplay];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have a few questions, why do I need a to connect the UiImageView to the storyboard in YourCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell? Aren't I supposed to create it dynamically in the constructor?

Comment: Not if you are using prototype cells. If all of your posts use the same cell design then you have to connect it to storyboard. Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, you'd better choose `UITableView` as the posts' container and inherit from `UITableViewCell` as your box view.

Detailedly speaking much more, suppose the class inherited from `UITableViewCell` named `MyTableViewCell`, and you treat its `contentView` as your `UIView *box`. After that, you could tell the `UITableView` to use your `MyTableViewCell` as the Cell by sending him `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Then, you can get `MyTableViewCell` instance by sending `UITableView` the 
`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` message. After being bound data (telling him display what posts), this instance can be returned to `UITableView`, which will arrange everything for you. Besides, these usually should be done in the `UITableView`'s `dataSource` method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.